# Toggle show/hide password on keydown/keyup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input, passwords

I want to show password when and only when the user **clicks and holds** the button. Which means when the user release the click it should be hidden again. I have tried `onkeyup` and `onkeydown` but I haven't got anywhere so far.

```js
function show() {
  $(pass).attr("type", "text");
}

function hide() {
  $(pass).attr("type", "password");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type='password' id='pass' value='abcdef' />
<button onkeydown='show()' onkeyup='hide()'>toggle</button>
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the [`mousedown`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mousedown) and [`mouseup`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseup) handlers:

```js
function show() {
  $(pass).attr("type", "text");
}

function hide() {
  $(pass).attr("type", "password");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type='password' id='pass' value='abcdef' />
<button onmousedown='show()' onmouseup='hide()'>toggle</button>
```

Comment: Ohh.. never knew there was a `onmouseup`. Thanks mate!

Answer (score 1):

You need `onmousedown` and `onmouseup`. To make it mobile friendly, use `ontouchstart` and `ontouchend`.

```js
function show() {
  document.getElementById("pass").setAttribute("type","text");
}

function hide() {
  document.getElementById("pass").setAttribute("type","password");
}
```

```html
<input type='password' id='pass' value='abcdef' />
<button onmousedown='show()' onmouseup='hide()'>toggle</button>
```